# Compare int with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, sql-server-express

I need to compare a int value with a datetime in a SQLExpress table.

Here´s the code I tried with, but didn´t work:

```
        String query = "select id, erstelldatum, enddatum, text, erledigt, prioritaet from Aufgaben where loginid = " + loginid + " AND erstelldatum LIKE "+ jahr +";";
```

So `jahr` is the year of the datetime and I want to get every date out of this year.

Just know how to compare it with a string but not with a datetime. Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside, please use parameterized SQL queries http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use Year function?

```
String query = "select id, erstelldatum, enddatum, text, erledigt, prioritaet from Aufgaben where loginid = " + loginid + " AND year(erstelldatum) = "+ jahr +";";
```

Comment: great, don´t know about this function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

String query = "select id, erstelldatum, enddatum, text, erledigt, prioritaet from Aufgaben where loginid = " + loginid + " AND erstelldatum >= @jahrfrom AND erstelldatum <= @jahrto;";

Pass in 2 variables with the 1st Jan for your year and the other variable as 31st Dec of the same year.

**OR**

Use the Year function in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Year is the same as using DATEPART, a function that will also let you get other parts of the date.